# Does anyone know where to find an "in-app-payment" example?

Tags: iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase

In an application I am developing I need to integrate the In-app-purchase concept, I have read the apple documentation but still don't completely understand how to completely integrate the system and make the call.

Does anyone know if there is an example out there to help me put me on track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this blog entry: http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-%E2%80%93-in-app-purchases/.

He goes through the steps required to add in-app purchasing.